# Angularjs $http Service POST, PUT and GET

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

I am developing application in AngularJS. But I still not so clear the difference of POST, PUT and GET. Usually I use $http GET when I get data from server when server side does not require any front end data to return data to client side as below.

```
$http.get(configSettings.baseUrl +"retrive_user.php").success(function (data) {

}).error(function() {
    console.log("error");
});
```

When I am using POST is when I server side require front end data in order to return data to client side as following.

```
$http({
    url: configSettings.baseUrl + "insert_message.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
        'username': username,
        'messageContent' : messsageContent,
        'sender_id': usernameID,
        'subscribeChannel' : subscribeChannel,
        'attachmentType' : attachmentType,
        'event' : 'chat_message'
    }
    }).success(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }).error(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
});
```

Even, I want to delete data or edit data in my MySQL database I am using POST method in angularjs as above and then in my PHP server side, I do like following to get data.

```
$chat_info = file_get_contents("php://input");
$chat_request = json_decode($chat_info,true);
@$username = $chat_request['username'];
@$messageContent = $chat_request['messageContent'];
@$sender_id = $chat_request['sender_id'];
@$subscribeChannel = $chat_request['subscribeChannel'];
@$attachmentType = $chat_request['attachmentType'];
@$event = $chat_request['event'];
```

I don't know whether this is a correct practice in RESTful API. I understand the difference between POST and GET. I my server side scripting, I just need to get data from client side in order to Create, Update, Read and Delete data from database. What so special about PUT, DELETE and PATCH in RESTful API?

Comment: There are many articles explaining these on the internet. Did you try reading any one of them?

Comment: Refer this once https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP verbs are probably one of the most cryptic things about the HTTP protocol.

**PUT** replace the **ENTIRE RESOURCE** with the **new representation provided** or you can say that if user want to add new record, he should use **PUT**.

On the other hand **PATCH** => As the name said its a kind of patch to update a piece of record. If user can only wants to update **a partial record**, say just an email address, he should use PATCH.

> As **PUT** method can update all the record so it need **more bandwidth** or handle full resources instead on
>   partial. So **PATCH** was introduced to reduce the **bandwidth**.

For example :- lets say I am sending new record to server i.e,

```
{ "first": "Anand Deep", "last": "Singh" }
```

So I will use **Put** because I am adding new record. But here has one problem with **Put** request that when I will use PUT, I have to send all two parameters that is first and last again. so it is mandatory to send all value again

But **Patch** only send the data which user want to update and it won't effecting or changing other data.So no need to send all value again.

So **PUT** for creating new record and **PATCH** is for updating existing record.

Same for **DELETE**, its tell to server that this request should delete the record which pass it to server.

For more details click on below image or this [URL](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html) :-

[image]

Comment: Yes, I understand HTTP is designed to enable communication between clients and servers. I understand the difference between POST and GET. For server side just need to get data from client side in order to Create, Update, Read and Delete data from database. We can achieve through POST and GET onlu. What so special about PUT, DELETE and PATCH in RESTful API?

Comment: I have updated my answer. I hope it clear your doubts. If you like it, you can accept my answer :)